# How to fill DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs.OldValues when using TemplateField

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a DetailsView control that's filled with a LinqDataSource without problems.

The user needs to upload a file when updating the information, so, I created a TemplateField with an asp:FileUpload control inside the EditItemTemplate (the itemTemplate is just an asp label).

The problem is that when I try to update the data, in the DetailsView.OnItemUpdating, the **DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs.OldValues** does not contain all the old values (nor the keys). Actually, it just has the **ArticleTitle** and **ArticleNumber**.

I thougth it was because the otheres where TemplateFields, so I changed the ArticleDesc from **BoundField** to **TemplateField**, added a Multiline Textbox to the **EditItemTemplate** and an asp Label to the **ItemTemplate**, and it worked fine (the original value of ArticleDesc was there).

This problem can be solved by other ways, like querying again for the data, but I don't like that solution. Besides, I want to understand why it happens.

**ASPX Page**

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="ModArticleDV" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" OnItemUpdated="ModArticleDV_ItemUpdated" OnItemUpdating="ModArticleDV_ItemUpdating" OnModeChanged="ModArticleDV_ModeChanged" OnDataBound="ModArticleDV_DataBound" OnDataBinding="ModArticleDV_DataBinding" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="ArticleDS" DataKeyNames="ArticleID">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ArticleID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ArticleID" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ArticleNumber" HeaderText="Número" SortExpression="ArticleNumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ArticleTitle" HeaderText="Título" SortExpression="ArticleTitle" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Archivo PDF" SortExpression="ArticleFile">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    Archivo Actual: <asp:Label ID="EditCurrentFileLbl" Text='<%# Eval("ArticleFile") %>' runat="server" /><br />
                    <label class="upload-file">Nuevo Archivo</label>: <asp:FileUpload ID="NewFileUpload" runat="server" CssClass="file-upload" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="CurrentFileLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ArticleFile") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Descripción" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="NewDescription" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Eval("ArticleDesc") %>' runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="CurrentDescription" Text='<%# Eval("ArticleDesc") %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cantidad de Páginas" SortExpression="ArticlePageCount" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="CountPagesUP" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CountPagesLink" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            Páginas: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="PageCountLabel" Text='<%# Eval("ArticlePageCount") %>' />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="CountPagesLink" runat="server" OnClick="CountPagesLink_Click">Contar Páginas</asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="CurrentPageCountLbl" Text='<%# Eval("ArticlePageCount") %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pertenece al" SortExpression="MagazineID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="NewMagazine" runat="server" DataSourceID="MagazineDS" DataTextField="MagazineTitle" DataValueField="MagazineID" OnPreRender="NewMagazine_PreRender"></asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="CurrentMagazineLbl" runat="server" OnPreRender="CurrentMagazineLbl_PreRender" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Autores" SortExpression="ArticleID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <label>Filtrar Autor</label>: <input type="text" class="search-in-list" title="Reduce la lista de autores. Ingrese el appellido paterno, materno y/o nombre. Debe incluir tildes de ser necesario." /><br />
                    <asp:ListBox ID="NewAuthors" runat="server" CssClass="list-to-search" SelectionMode="Multiple" DataSourceID="AuthorDS" DataTextField="AuthorFullName" DataValueField="AuthorID" Height="206px" Width="292px" OnDataBound="NewAuthors_DataBound"></asp:ListBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="CurrentAuthorsLbl" runat="server" OnPreRender="CurrentAuthorsLbl_PreRender" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="MagazineID" Text='<%# Eval("MagazineID") %>' runat="server" />
                    <asp:Label ID="CurrentAuthorID" runat="server" OnPreRender="CurrentAuthorID_PreRender" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" UpdateText="Guardar" CancelText="Cancelar" SelectText="Seleccionar" NewText="Nuevo" InsertText="Agregar" EditText="Editar" DeleteText="Borrar" ControlStyle-CssClass="command-field-control" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="ArticleDS" runat="server" ContextTypeName="LinqToSql.FinderSchemaDataContext" EnableUpdate="True" OrderBy="ArticleID" TableName="Articles" EnableDelete="True" EntityTypeName=""></asp:LinqDataSource>
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="MagazineDS" runat="server" ContextTypeName="LinqToSql.FinderSchemaDataContext" EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="PublishYear, MagazineNumber" TableName="Magazines" Select="new (MagazineID, MagazineNumber, MagazineName, PublishYear, String.Format(&quot;Volumen {0} del año {1}&quot;, MagazineNumber.ToString(), PublishYear.ToString()) AS MagazineTitle)"></asp:LinqDataSource>
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="AuthorDS" runat="server" ContextTypeName="LinqToSql.FinderSchemaDataContext" EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="AuthorFName, AuthorMName, AuthorName" TableName="Authors" Select="new (AuthorID, AuthorFName, AuthorMName, AuthorName, String.Format(&quot;{0} {1} {2}&quot;, AuthorFName.ToString(), AuthorMName.ToString(), AuthorName.ToString()) AS AuthorFullName)" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void ModArticleDV_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    Messages.InnerHtml = "";

    try
    {
        Messages.InnerHtml += "<h3>Old Values</h3><br />";
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in e.OldValues)
        {
            Messages.InnerHtml += String.Format("Key: {1} - Value: {0}<br />", de.Value, de.Key);
        }

        Messages.InnerHtml += "<h3>New Values</h3><br />";
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in e.NewValues)
        {
            Messages.InnerHtml += String.Format("Key: {1} - Value: {0}<br />", de.Value, de.Key);
        }

        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Messages.InnerHtml += ex.Message;
    }
}
```

This shows me only the ArticleNumber and ArticleTitle

**What Have I tried?**

- Using Bind instead of Eval
- Using a default DetailsView and LinqDataSource fills the e.OldValues with the original values, but I didn't notice the difference :(.
- I have read many times the MSDN documentation on DetailsView, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs and many other resources, but none gave me a hint (I read somewhere that it may be because of the TemplateField(s), but in the tests I run, they work ok).
- This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484930/gridview-template-field-datasource) is related, but that's the way I've always added data to TemplateField.

If someone could give me something to read to understand why it happens or if someone could tell me where to fill the OldValues (other than the ItemUpdating event), it would be great :).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that the dictionaries e.(New|Old)Values are not filled with the data in **TemplateField**(s).

My solution (I don't know of any better) was to use a hidden TemplateField (Visible="false") and, inside the ItemTemplate, add the original values with labels (asp:Label) then access them using DetailsView.FindControl("control_id"):

```
<TemplateField Visible="false">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="OriginalValue1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column1") %>' />
    <asp:Label ID="OriginalValueN" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ColumnN") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</TemplateField>
```

And in the **Code Behind**:

```
// DetailsView.ID = "MyDetailsView";
Label original1 = (Label)MyDetailsView.FindControl("OriginalValue1");
Label originalN = (Label)MyDetailsView.FindControl("OriginalValueN");
```

For some reason I can't explain, some test I've run with TemplateFields worked (the data was added to the dictionary without my intervention), that's why I was confused and thought it was an error.

Anyway, the problem is now solved and I hope this helps someone :).